# Adding a Custom Image to a GUI based Game

Tags: java, user-interface

I am in the process of programming a game and I would like to change the black background to a custom image. How can this be done?

[image: snake]

```
setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

I've tried to add this inside the method:

```
new ImageIcon("src/image/TheSnakeBody.png")
```

But it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
private void RunningBoard() {
    addKeyListener(new KeysAdapter());
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));
    Icons.IconsUsed();
    RunningGame();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to create a class that extends [`javax.swing.JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and override the method `paintComponent()`. Did you try searching for the words ___swing custom painting___? Better yet, just try searching for ___java swing snake game___

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's actually no such thing as background in game development.

Games, as being rendered, aren't static/moving images on other image. The whole screen is being rendered many times a second.

So to achieve the "effect" of black background, you need to first draw a black rectangle on your screen, and then your other figutres.

```
setColor(Color.BLUE);
drawRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080); // or your screen size
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to do that, but it won't let me. Nothing happens, when I do that. I've just uploaded the method code.

Comment: @RuneWarz You see, `setBackground()` and `setColor()` don't actually paint anything. They're just setting a color that should be used for future operations.

Comment: What's in `RunningGame` method?

Comment: there's where the snake and apple is being located to the game area.